# Blog post url rewrite

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite, blog

I'm using BlogMate extension for my magento site.

This is my blog url http://mypage.com/blog

But if I click on a post, it will access to http://mypage.com/post_slug

Is there anyway to change the post url from http://mypage.com/post_slug to http://mypage.com/blog/post_slug

http://mypage.com/blog/post_slug is a 404 page currently.

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a paid extension, there is no way for us to help you effectively. I assume the extension is using core rewrites to add post titles, so if you change the rewrite creation, the url will change.